# Python JSON фильтр по значениям

Tags: python, json

Есть строка:

```
{
  "success": "true",
  "date": "0",
  "base": [ 
    {"item": "marker", "color": "red", "permanent": "yes"}, 
    {"item": "marker", "color": "blue", "permanent": "no"},
    {"item": "marker", "color": "green", "permanent": "yes"},
    {"item": "pen", "color": "black", "permanent": "yes"},
    {"item": "pen", "color": "white", "permanent": "yes"},
    {"item": "pen", "color": "grey", "permanent": "yes"}
  ]
}
```

Необходимо отфильтровать по двум значениям: `"item" = "marker"`, `"permanent" = "yes"`. 
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dct = {
  "success": "true",
  "date": "0",
  "base": [ 
    {"item": "marker", "color": "red", "permanent": "yes"}, 
    {"item": "marker", "color": "blue", "permanent": "no"},
    {"item": "marker", "color": "green", "permanent": "yes"},
    {"item": "pen", "color": "black", "permanent": "yes"},
    {"item": "pen", "color": "white", "permanent": "yes"},
    {"item": "pen", "color": "grey", "permanent": "yes"}
  ]
}
print(list(filter(lambda d: d['item'] == 'marker' and d['permanent'] == 'yes', dct['base'])))

[{'item': 'marker', 'color': 'red', 'permanent': 'yes'}, {'item': 'marker', 'color': 'green', 'permanent': 'yes'}]
```